# How to set footer to 100% if body is 95%?

Tags: html, css

I've been tasked with changing a website around a bit, and right now, the website has a responsive layout that is 95% of the viewports width, body-wise, so it will adjust if resized.

This is great, I want it to keep doing that, but I want the footer to have a side-to-side calm blue background, and I'm not able to come up with a way to do that for some reason.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You should post some code, and, even better, a link to your website or a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body` contains all the other elements. You thus aren't supposed to have one larger than `body` inside of it.

Although you could position it absolutely to the bottom-left corner (`position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;`) with a width of `100%` and possibly make it work, I'd suggest you instead make a container element, perhaps a `div`, inside of the `body` element that contains your 95%-width elements and place the footer outside of that container.

I am not sure of which method is more reliable, however.

Answer (score 2):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXspx/)

***HTML***

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>

    <section>MAIN CONTENT</section>

    <footer> FOOTER </footer>
</div>​
```

***CSS***

```css
#container {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    background: honeydew;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: beige;
    margin-left: -2.5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried to wrap existing 'header'component by other 'wrapper' component (div, span, etc.)? Example:

```
<div id="wrapper" width="100%"

<div id="header" width="95%">
  some header stuff here
</div>

<!-- foo bar --> 

<div id="footer" width="100%">
  my footer
</div>

</div>
```